# How to install WampServer on Windows 10 IoT core?

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot, php

I would like to write a PHP application on Windows 10 IoT for the Pi, is there any anyway to install WampServer on Windows 10 IoT for the Pi?

Comment: if your are developing in php would it not be simpler to stick with raspian as the os?

Comment: I doubt it, Windows 10 for the Pi is not a full desktop like the version that runs on your PC.

Comment: means i can't use wamp server on windows iot version?

Comment: PHP is not really built for Windows platform to start with. Sure there have been many progressions getting PHP to run on Windows. Visual Studio even support writting code in PHP and SDK for hosting PHP inside IIS but that relies on some hard core cygwin stuff.. that just does not work on Windows IoT - If we had Linux containers, then sure. but currently there are no containers on IoT at all. So you can only use Universal Apps or console apps at the moment, based on the .NET Framework only. Frankly, you will much better time writing .NET for Linux using .NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 IOT **is not** a full blown Windows desktop environment. If you want to use Windows 10 IOT, you will need to use `.NET` solutions.

If you wish to develop in PHP, I highly recommend you use Raspbian.